# using sessions: am I abusing it?

Tags: asp.net

Let's say I have a site where a reporting page will contain user-specific daily reports.

By default, the user lands on today's report but then if he clicks on a calendar control and selects a new date, a new report will load for that day. What I want to do is use sessions as a cache for reports. The first time he loads a report for a day, it's loaded from the database into the session and then from the session to the page. Each time he loads a new report for a date, the logic first checks to see if this particular report is in the session and only if it's not is it loaded from the DB. A report has about 15 columns and is made up of about 300-500 rows per day. What will be stored in the session is a dictionary of lists of objects, with the date as the key and the list as the value. I'm using InProc session. I'm also considering storing several other dictionaries as well for other lists of objects.

Is this an efficient way to make the most of the .net framework? If it doesn't actually improve performance over making calls to the data source, will it make it slower? I'm looking to build something that'll scale to about 500-1000 simultaneous users or so.

Thanks.

Comment: Session is not designed to work with caches. You should use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) instead

Comment: But that's not the same - the Cache is shared, Session is per-user.

Comment: Are the reports specific to each user?

Comment: are you using inproc session?

Comment: Append session id for each cache keys and it won't be shared anymore :)

Comment: what's the benefit of using cache with a dictionary instead of using session?

Comment: How big are the reports in size, ie. memory-wise?

Comment: @Lasse: don't know. How do I find out?

Comment: If you don't have an accurate number you should have an estimate, just sum up all the information stored, like "how much text", "how many int32's", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your pre-optimizing to me.  Have you run any performance tests to verify that you get any benefit at all to putting it in Session (or Cache)?

Have your users expressed concern over the performance?

For me, I wouldn't consider optimizing to any kind of cache until I knew I had a performance issue, and then I would look at **why** I had the performance problem, and optimize **that**

Comment: I'm doing the first build. I just think that this problem will come up because the report plays an important role in the app and will be called many many times. I want to avoid going back to the DB to get the same data. I am also thinking of dumping the reports in XML files on session end and loading them from there on session start. Thoughts?

Comment: @frenchie That's exactly what I'm saying. Have you run any performance tests to verify that you have an issue? Load tests? It's always better to measure first, not just guess. If you run tests to figure out where your system is slow, you might find out something completely different than what you're thinking right now.  What if the database call isn't slowing you down at all, it's that nested for loop you forgot to refactor in your ORM piece, etc. etc. You won't know any of these things until you measure.

Comment: @frenchie yes, you're testing should be done in a separate environment from production. A lot of people do this in Staging, which is a exact replica of production, so if you find something in Staging, then you can expect the same results in Production under the same load constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are striking differences between cache and session state:

- Cache is **server-based** but session is **user-based** (can be across multiple servers)
- Cache is usually URL-based so **if the URL is the same for all users, this cannot be implemented via cache**.
- Cache will be recycled and memory reclaimed when server is close to out of memory (so **you will not get an `OutOfMemory` exception using cache**) but session just grows and you will get an `OutOfMemory` if you are using in-process sessions and not.
- Session is usually used for user level state that has to be stored but cache is meant for performance boosting.

With all above, and considering your requirement, **you had better use cache unless the URL is the same for all users.** If you are using session state, *you need to be very careful as just a little performance nicety can kill your website*.

Comment: The data I'm looking to put in the session is user specific. If I implement what I am discussing, do you think this could negatively impact performance? I'm looking to build an app that'll initially support up to 500 simultaneous users before having to make architectural changes. Thanks.